# Google ads are not loading

Tags: java, android, admob

I am new to this. I have been trying to connect an app to Admob. When I attempt to connect, it always triggers the onAdFailedToLoad() method. This is the same for banner, interstitial and rewarded ads. Please what am I doing wrong?

In the MainActivity, I have:

`@Override
public void onCreate(BundleInstanceState bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this, "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX");

    //   --- Admob ---
    view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

    Admob.createLoadBanner(getApplicationContext(), view);
    Admob.loadBanner();
    //   --- *** ---

    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}`

In the Admob class, I have:

`public static void createLoadBanner(final Context context, View view) {
    mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
            addTestDevice("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX").//ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
            build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Banner Ad has been loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Banner Ad has been closed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Banner Ad has been opened.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Banner Ad is being redirected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Banner Ad failed to load!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // loadBanner();
        }
    });
}

public static void loadBanner() {
    if (!mAdView.isLoading()) mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().
            addTestDevice("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX").//ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
            build());
}`

Answer (score 1):

add this in manifest file under application tag

```
   <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
      android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

follow this url to make sure you have implemented all steps:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: I did that already. I'm sorry I didn't put up my manifest codes. I thought it might have something to do with the codes.